# toggle image src

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

Need to change image back ground when click on HREF with other function

```
<a href="#" id="showbilled_account">
    <img alt="" src="images/btn_showBillAccounts.gif" id="showBillAccounts" />
</a>
```

there some other toggles are Woking with same button. All the functions are working fine.
unfortunately I have to click twice to change image src

Here is my script code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var valueTextbox = $("#FilterTextBox").val();
        $('#tbl_container tbody tr:not(:contains("' + valueTextbox + '"))').hide();
        $('#tbl_container tbody tr:contains("' + valueTextbox + '")').show();
        $(".pagination").hide();
        $(".searchresult.spacetop").hide();
        $(".exp_coll_wrap_alone").hide();

    $("#showbilled_account").click(function() { 
        var valueTextbox = $("#FilterTextBox").val();
        $('#tbl_container tbody tr:contains("' + valueTextbox + '")').toggle();
        $('#tbl_container tbody tr:contains("")').toggle(); 
        $(".pagination").toggle();
        $(".exp_coll_wrap_alone").toggle();

        $(function(){
            $('#showbilled_account').toggle(function(){
             $('#showBillAccounts').attr("src","images/btn_hideBillingAccounts.gif" );
            },function(){
              $('#showBillAccounts').attr("src", "images/btn_showBillAccounts.gif" );
            });
        });
 });

});
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered using classes and CSS background-image?

Comment: @Jørgen let me try thinking that way. 
Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use if statement

```
if( $("#showBillAccounts").attr("src") == "images/btn_hideBillingAccounts.gif" ) {
  $('#showBillAccounts').attr("src", "images/btn_showBillAccounts.gif" );
} else {
$('#showBillAccounts').attr("src","images/btn_hideBillingAccounts.gif" );
} });
```

like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var valueTextbox = $("#FilterTextBox").val();
        $('#tbl_container tbody tr:not(:contains("' + valueTextbox + '"))').hide();
        $('#tbl_container tbody tr:contains("' + valueTextbox + '")').show();
        $(".pagination").hide();
        $(".searchresult.spacetop").hide();
        $(".exp_coll_wrap_alone").hide();

    $("#showbilled_account").click(function() { 
        var valueTextbox = $("#FilterTextBox").val();
        $('#tbl_container tbody tr:contains("' + valueTextbox + '")').toggle();
        $('#tbl_container tbody tr:contains("")').toggle(); 
        $(".pagination").toggle();
        $(".exp_coll_wrap_alone").toggle();

        if( $("#showBillAccounts").attr("src") == "images/btn_hideBillingAccounts.gif" ) {
            $('#showBillAccounts').attr("src", "images/btn_showBillAccounts.gif" );
        } else {
            $('#showBillAccounts').attr("src","images/btn_hideBillingAccounts.gif" );
        } });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. So there is need for css with this code ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer using background-images for the element and toggle the class on click:

```
<a href="#" id="showbilled_account" class="showBillingAccounts"></a>
```

Note that I have removed the img tag, and the anchor essentially have no content. By specifying height and width for the a, you'll have a button.

```
$('#showbilled_account').click(function(){
  toggleClass('showBillingAccounts', 'hideBillingAccounts');
}
```

CSS:

```
.showBillingAccounts{ background-image : url("images/btn_showBillAccounts.gif"); }
.hideBillingAccounts{ background-image : url("images/btn_hideBillAccounts.gif"); }
#showbilled_account{ height: 100px; width: 100px; padding: 0 }
```

This way you keep the HTML more semantically correct and it becomes more maintainable.
Note that the size of the #showbilled_account item should fit the size of the image.

Comment: When use as image background. problem is that using <img > couldn't show images with out mention widht and height in css :(

Comment: You won't need the img tag if you use CSS. Do you need to scale the images client side in order for them to fit? If you can avoid that you should, and either scale the images yourself, making them fit your design.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way too, by changing from this

```
$(function(){
   $('#showbilled_account').toggle(function(){
     $('#showBillAccounts').attr("src","images/btn_hideBillingAccounts.gif" );
   },function(){
        $('#showBillAccounts').attr("src", "images/btn_showBillAccounts.gif" );
     });
});
```

to this

```
      var mSrc = ($(#showBillAccounts).attr("src") === "images/btn_hideBillingAccounts.gif") ? "images/btn_showBillAccounts.gif" : "images/btn_hideBillingAccounts.gif";
      $(#showBillAccounts).attr("src", mSrc);
```